# subselect ininsert statement for 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

This is my sql:

```
insert into
        LIST_ENTRIES(MANDATOR_KEY, SERVICE_IDENTIFIER, SERVICE_IDENTIFIER2,
        REASON_CODE, BLOCK_TYPE, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO, LISTS_KEY, VERSION)
        values
        ('Abra2', 'abrakadabra',NULL,8,0,SYSDATE,SYSDATE,
        SELECT DISTINCT ID, VERSION FROM LISTS
        WHERE SERVICE_KEY = '10s3f10-111'
        AND LIST_COLOR = 2
        AND MANDATOR_KEY = 'ASD');
```

and i get exception as

```
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

if i just run subselect:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ID, VERSION FROM LISTS
            WHERE SERVICE_KEY = '10s3f10-111'
            AND LIST_COLOR = 2
            AND MANDATOR_KEY = 'ASD'
```

i get result as `11, 145`

what is wrong? Why i can not with subselect insert 2 vales. I check this manual and here works:
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO LIST_ENTRIES(MANDATOR_KEY, SERVICE_IDENTIFIER, SERVICE_IDENTIFIER2, REASON_CODE, BLOCK_TYPE, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO, LISTS_KEY, VERSION)
SELECT  'Abra2', 'abrakadabra',NULL,8,0,SYSDATE,SYSDATE, ID, VERSION 
FROM    LISTS
WHERE   SERVICE_KEY = '10s3f10-111' AND 
        LIST_COLOR = 2 AND 
        MANDATOR_KEY = 'ASD'
```

Comment: aaaa i forget to add select infront. THX! You save my day :D